# what delegate method that will called when an app close in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

just like my question, I just want to know what delegate method that will called when an app close? I was thought that it was ApplicationWillTerminate, but no, that delegate method just called if the app spend to much memory and no memory left, so the system called that method.

So, what delegate method that will called when an app close?

Comment: What do you mean my close? Close by pressing Home button or by pressing (-) minus button?

Comment: close by pressing (-) minus button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: this method called when the app minimize, using home button pressed, see my comment please :)

Comment: sorry. what i was meant to say: this is the delegate you need to check and do your stuff here, because its the last delegate called before someone kills your app (because killing you app is only possible if the app is in background).